# How do I get an interchangeable lens camera on a tripod to focus on my face while I'm taking selfies?

Tags: autofocus, self-portrait, face-detection

I want to place the camera on a tripod, frame the shot, set the timer, stand where I want to be photographed, have the camera detect my face (sharp focus) and take the picture.

My DSLR can't do this. The focus is locked once up I activate the timer.

I've read that quite a lot of cameras, even flagship mirrorless cameras can't do this. Sure there must be a way. What am I missing? What should I look for in the camera specs to find a camera that can do this?

Comment: Personally, I don't know why this question was closed so quickly! Come on friends! Let's work with question-askers! At least for more than an hour! If you are interested in this topic, there is another (open and upvoted) question on our site here... [When setting my Canon camera on a timer, how do I force it to focus at the time the shot is taken instead of when the timer is set?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97071)

Comment: You don't need a $2000 camera, you need a $10 wired remote controller (or $40 for radio one) on practically any DSLR,  and if you have a recent camera, you can probably also use your phone as a remote controller.

Comment: @osullic Agreed that this is a good question. Voting for reopen. Given your rep, you can cast a reopen vote?

Comment: @osullic, I did a massive title re-edit, and edited to remove the shopping bits, and then voted to reopen. Hopefully, it wasn't a step too far. :D

Answer (score 3):

I am going to steal Xenoid's comment.

Depending on the model of your camera, you can try a wireless remote trigger. I have used the Amazon basics on a Nikon. They are as cheap as $15.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=remote+trigger+dslr&crid=15PLBMFRT3S35&sprefix=remote+trigger+dslr%2Caps%2C123&ref=nb_sb_noss_2

See your user´s manual to see compatibilities. In general, they work with a decent DSLR even some years old.  Try different patterns of focus points on your camera. If you have a framing defined, you can even try a single focus point.

These are in fact easier to use than self-timer, you can be in place and trigger several shots without the need to stand up. It also avoids the problem you have of the focus being locked on while triggering the timer.

---

Make some tests to see what aperture is open enough for your light and bokeh situation, and closed enough to have the depth of field you need to stay in focus.

---

Another option is that you leave the manual focus on a defined distance. But that is a very rudimentary approach.

---

See if your camera has a live view focus system. Cannon dual pixel is one good example.

---

If you want a new camera, one first thing to consider is a flip screen and then face or eye recognition and tracking, but again a remote trigger is a great asset to have.

Answer (score 1):

Modern DSLRs and MILCs have both have face detection, sometimes as a separate focusing mode or a setting. DSLRs obviously need to be in Live View mode for that. Whether camera auto-focuses before taking a picture in self-timer or remote release mode depends on the camera and is usually described in the manual.
However, if you are photographing yourself from stretched hand you can pre-focus on your fingers while looking in viewfinder and then your face will be in focus when you hold the camera at same distance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this the old fashioned way: Focus on an object which is the same distance that you will be standing from the camera, then, set the focus to manual. If there isn't a convenient object, use a rock, leaf, stick, or some other object and place it where you'll stand and focus on the object, then set the focus to manual.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and works well.

I have a Nikon Z fc APSC MILC which has Self-portrait functionality. The monitor can be tilted to yourself position (the camera automatically sets to self-portrait mode).

I was seated at about 6 feet away from the camera, with the camera set on a tripod. I could see my face in the monitor.

I used my smartphone app (Nikon Snapbridge) to connect to my camera (they are paired earlier) via Bluetooth. I can focus and see the eye-detection (a yellow box) following one of my eyes in the monitor. And, released the shutter from my app.

I have used the Auto-area Auto Focus (people) setting, so the camera detects and focuses on human faces or eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink how to accomplish the task. But I would imagine any of the new mirrorless cameras with eye detection/tracking AF could do it the way you envision.

The *easiest* way to do this is to use a camera that has wifi/bluetooth wireless capabilities, and an app on your smartphone to help you compose (by showing you what the camera sees), adjust exposure settings, set focus, and trip the shutter. It's far more precise and convenient to do than the preset-the-camera, set-the-timer-and-run and then rinse repeat to adjust framing and manual focus, etc.

You can use a wireless remote that lets you set AF with a half-press on the remote button.

You can manually focus on where your face is going to be by using a stand-in object or just guesstimating with zone focus. Stopping down your lens can make your focus target bigger. It's how I used to selfie with an OM-10 and an ultrapod in ye olden days of film.